# Solr Index and Document Size

Tags: solr

When I look at Solr admin console under the "Replication" section , it shows the index size , is this the size of the index by itself or the size of the index plus all the documents in the collection?

If its only the size of the index by itself,  then how can I see the size of of the documents in the collection ?

Does Solr load all the index at once into memory  ? If yes, then whats the Solr policy if the size of the index+various caches is more than the available physical memory , should we  expect Out of Memory exceptions ?

Answer (score -1):

It is actually the size of the whole documents + indexes. Having said that, Solr won't all load of them in the memory. It will fetch the index from the disk as and then needed.